# How to redirect URLs with "%20" via htaccess? Nothing works

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect URLs from an old domain to a new domain. I have a problem with URLs with spaces in them. They look like this:

domain.com/Typ%2010%20(PR70),2,489.490.html

and they redirect to this:

new-domain.com/category-name **/Typ%2010%20(PR70),2,489.490.html**

The things I tried:

- using quotation marks around the old link
- replacing %20 with "\ ", "\s", "[\s]", "(\s)"
- using RedirectMatch 301
- using RewriteRule
- using combinations of everything above

Nothing works. I've read about a dozen topics on here explaining what I should do, I followed them, and they didn't work. The best I've managed to achieve was 500 server error.

Comment: did you try NE (no escape) flag : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Comment: I will try this, thank you.

Comment: It didn't help. I've got some results for yet another link. What worked was using "\" before brackets, as well as using spaces instead of "%20".

But I still have the same problem for the link above, which was indexed by google. It still won't redirect properly.